# How to model sockets with RAII

Tags: c++, sockets, raii

I'm a newbie at C++ (coming from C). I understand conceptually how RAII should work, but I have trouble fitting a simple socket connection handler into it.

Current code:

```
void accept_ev(event_handler::token &t, int listenfd)
{
    int newfd = accept(listenfd, NULL, NULL);

    if (newfd < 0)
        throw api_server_accept_failed(*this, errno);

    connections.insert(api_server_connection(newfd));
}
```

This is obviously not safe, since api_server_connection constructor might raise an exception before assigning the fd to its member variable.

So my next thought was to move the accept into the constructor. The problem is I really want api_server_connection to be agnostic about where the fd came from. E.g. if I want to support inetd in the future it might just as well be passed into the program as fd 0.

So how do I do this. Should I use different constructors for each way to obtain an fd? Should I perhaps make subclasses? Another option could be to have a lambda function?

Or should I just catch any error and close the fd in the caller in that case?

Comment: Have you looked at/read about how [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) works? (have you considered skipping this entirely and just using ASIO?)

Comment: How can `api_server_connection` raise an exception? You haven't shown us that code.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I haven't written it yet... but I know it'll have pimpl, which means memory allocation, which could fail.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I haven't, but this question isn't really about sockets (I hesitated to add that tag), but rather RAII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring, sockets for the moment, what you usually want to do is divide things into two phases.

In the first phase, you do things that may throw, but if they do, you can restore the system to a sane state (preferably a state as if nothing happened at all).

In the second phase, you do things that you may not be able to undo, but that you know for sure will never throw.

To do that, you need some assurance about what can/will throw and (particularly) some assurances about at least a few rather specific operations that can never throw at all (e.g., swapping two items).

To facilitate this, you normally want to do that restoration to a sane state in the dtor, so if an exception is thrown, the destructor will clean up automatically.

Unfortunately, it's difficult to say a lot more than that about your specific code/situation, because we simply don't know enough about the classes you're using.

Comment: I think you actually got me thinking in the right way, so I suppose I should accept this. I'll create an fd_guard class and stick the fd into it first, in a way that can't fail. Then I can create the connection object without worry and let it inherit the fd or the fd_guard.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in order to use the RAII you have to think in object oriented way. So I see that you trying to implement the server class using c++. In this case you will use the RAII only for the server initialization that mean that you will write the code and finish it when the server will start to listen to the port. The last function call in your constructor must be listen or start connections thread. After that you have to implement the second thread which will handle the clients connections. The second thread will call the accept in order to accept the clients and will be in iteration while the server is working. In your destructor you just need to set your listening flag to false and wait for the accept thread to be terminated after that just close all of your sockets.